# Is postgres throttling my queries?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to run the following query against postgresql using npgsql:

```
SELECT product_id, product_id_type, asin
FROM products 
WHERE invalid_id = FALSE and last_update is null or last_update < (CURRENT_DATE - 1) AND product_id_type IN ('EAN', 'UPC');
```

When I run it from 0xDBE I get a resultset of 500. If I change the query to just SELECT COUNT(*)... then it tells me there are > 6000 rows.

When I run it from Ngpgsql I get 0 results. My IDataReader returns "false" for HasRows and Read() returns false as well. However, if I limit my query to 1000 results by appending "LIMIT 1000" then I get results.

Is there a "resource governor" setting somewhere in Postgres that is controlling this?

Yes, I realize I shouldn't be returning that many, I was being lazy. I've corrected the problem, but since I'm trying to learn more about postgres I'd like to know where this setting is managed and what topic I might read to learn more about it.

Thanks

**Update**
@Peter-Headland answered that PostgreSQL isn't the source of this issue, which technically answers my question. However, the root of my question is what the actual cause is. I don't see anything in the Npgsql documentation to account for this behavior. Why would I need to add LIMIT to my query to get any results?

Comment: Have you reproduced the issue? Doing so would eliminate the risk that there was an open transaction.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reproduced the issue, unless you mean developed a reproducible example? Not yet, but that would probably help me get an answer, so I'll get one posted. That said, there is no open transaction the data in the table is static - it's a list of products that I want to check daily. It was working against a SQL Server database before and I just migrated the data to Postgres by replacing my provider and migrating my sql queries.

Answer (score 3):

The PostgreSQL database will return all the rows selected by a query; there is no secret limiter ("resource governor"). Any discrepancies you observe are artifacts of the tools you are using or the result of uncommitted transactions (which would cause different sets of rows to be visible in different contexts). Tools may add limits to the size of result set they fetch; those limits may be configurable within the tools, but has no effect upon the core behavior of the database.

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question I asked, but I still don't know what's causing it to do this. I need to be able to work with this in the future but I can't find anything in the Npgsql documentation to account for this either.